# Pentaho rest api call respond 401

Tags: java, rest, api, pentaho

When we call from client application Pentaho rest api returns 401 UnAuthirised status.
We are using basic authentiaction for the api call

```
curl -X GET  https://domain_name/pentaho/api/userrolelist/roles  -H 'authorization: Basic cG93ZXJ1c2VyOnBvd2VydXNlckAxMjM='
```

But this same api call from browser after login to pentaho it will return result

Its has worked for earliear after few days its shows 401;

Comment: FWIW the header should be capitalised; as in `Authorization`.

Comment: also tried with that